# Run-time error '2498' - Access 2010 VBA - DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writing a script that filters a query based off user input, then data in this query will be used to make a new table `qryMyExportedData`. From there, the data will be exported to `ExportedData.xlsx`. When I attempt to run my code, I get the following error:

`Run-time error '2498': An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments.`

My code:

```
Private Sub Query_Click()
  Dim strExport as String
  strExport = "SELECT * FROM qryCostDepLosses WHERE [Maintenance Type]  = '" & Me.MainType & "' AND [Date] = #" & Me.Date & "#"

  Set qdfNew = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQueryDef", strExport)

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myExportQueryDef", CurrentProject.Path & "\ExportedData.xlsx", "True"

  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdfNew.Name 'cleanup

End Sub
```

I have narrowed down the error to the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` line. The strExport looks as it should, I believe. The data is exported to myExportQueryDef as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are attempting to send a Boolean as a String.  So the code should look like this:

```vb
Private Sub Query_Click()
  Dim strExport as String
  strExport = "SELECT * FROM qryCostDepLosses WHERE [Maintenance Type]  = '" & Me.MainType & "' AND [Date] = #" & Me.Date & "#"

  Set qdfNew = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("myExportQueryDef", strExport)

  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "myExportQueryDef", CurrentProject.Path & "\ExportedData.xlsx", True

  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdfNew.Name 'cleanup

End Sub
```

Basically just remove the quotes from around `True`.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.  I used this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx and went through it by argument to see what wasn't matching up.